# Submitting parallel jobs on HTCondor, using python

Tags: python, for-loop, parallel-processing, pickle, condor

I am trying to submit parallel jobs in a loop on HTCondor, following is a simple example of the python script -

```
test_mus = np.linspace(0, 5, 10)
results = [pyhf.infer.hypotest(test_mu, data, model)
        for test_mu in test_mus]
```

I would like to submit each job (`results`), over the for loop (so 10 jobs) simultaneously to 10 machines, and then combine all the results in a pickle.

I have the submission script for this job as below -

```
executable            = CLs.sh
+JobFlavour           = "testmatch"
arguments             = $(ClusterId) $(ProcId)
Input                 = LHpruned_NEW_32.json
output                = output_sigbkg/CLs.$(ClusterId).$(ProcId).out
error                 = output_sigbkg/CLs.$(ClusterId).$(ProcId).err
log                   = output_sigbkg/CLs.$(ClusterId).log
transfer_input_files  = CLs_test1point.py, LHpruned_NEW_32.json
should_transfer_files = YES
queue
```

I would like to know how to submit 10 jobs, to parallelize the jobs.
Thank you !

Best,
Shreya

Answer (score 2):

It's worth looking at the description of how to submit a HTCondor DAG via Python [here](https://htcondor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apis/python-bindings/tutorials/DAG-Creation-And-Submission.html#Describing-goatbrot-as-an-HTCondor-job). In your case, if you install the [htcondor](https://pypi.org/project/htcondor/) Python module, you could do something like:

```py
import htcondor
from htcondor import dags

# create the submit script
sub = htcondor.Submit(
    {
        "executable": "CLs.sh",
        "+JobFlavour": "testmatch",
        "arguments": "$(ClusterId) $(ProcId)",
        "Input": "LHpruned_NEW_32.json",
        "output": "output_sigbkg/CLs.$(ClusterId).$(ProcId).out",
        "error": "output_sigbkg/CLs.$(ClusterId).$(ProcId).err",
        "log": "output_sigbkg/CLs.$(ClusterId).log",
        "transfer_input_files": "CLs_test1point.py, LHpruned_NEW_32.json",
        "should_transfer_files": "YES",
    }
)

# create DAG
dag = dags.DAG()

# add layer with 10 jobs
layer = dag.layer(
    name="CLs_layer",
    submit_description=sub,
    vars=[{} for i in range(10)],
)

# write out the DAG to current directory
dagfile = dags.write_dag(dag, ".")
```

You can use the `vars` argument to add macros giving values for each specific job if you want, e.g., if you wanted `mu` as one of the executable arguments you could switch this to:

```py
import htcondor
from htcondor import dags

# create the submit script
sub = htcondor.Submit(
    {
        "executable": "CLs.sh",
        "+JobFlavour": "testmatch",
        "arguments": "$(ClusterId) $(ProcId) $(MU)",
        "Input": "LHpruned_NEW_32.json",
        "output": "output_sigbkg/CLs.$(ClusterId).$(ProcId).out",
        "error": "output_sigbkg/CLs.$(ClusterId).$(ProcId).err",
        "log": "output_sigbkg/CLs.$(ClusterId).log",
        "transfer_input_files": "CLs_test1point.py, LHpruned_NEW_32.json",
        "should_transfer_files": "YES",
    }
)

# create DAG
dag = dags.DAG()

# add layer with 10 jobs
layer = dag.layer(
    name="CLs_layer",
    submit_description=sub,
    vars=[{"MU": mu} for mu in np.linspace(0, 5, 10)],
)

# write out the DAG to current directory
dagfile = dags.write_dag(dag, ".")
```

Once the DAG is created, you can either submit it as normal with `condor_submit_dag` from the terminal, or submit it via Python using the instructions [here](https://htcondor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apis/python-bindings/tutorials/DAG-Creation-And-Submission.html#Submit-the-DAG-via-the-Python-bindings).

> Note: your `+JobFlavour` value for the submit file will actually get converted to `MY.JobFlavour` in the file that gets created, but that's ok and means the same thing.